# Pass Lat Lng var to initialize function google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I Have a jQuery script that makes an Ajax call to convert a zipcode to latitude & longitude.The zipcode is retrieved from a hidden input field. That part works fine. And the ajax result gives me the correct lat/long.

**Piece of HTML**

`<input id="zipcode" type="hidden" value="1010AK">`

**Ajax call in jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
       var zipcode = jQuery('input#zipcode').val();    
       $.ajax({
       url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=netherlands&components=postal_code:"+zipcode+"&sensor=false",
       method: "POST",
       success:function(data){
             latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
             longitude= data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
             coords = latitude+','+longitude;
             //console.log(coords);
           }    
      });   
});
```

Outside (below) the document ready function i have an initialize() function and i want to be able to pass my `coords` var to that function so i've the correct latitude and longitude.

**Init function (after ajax call):**

```
    function init() {
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 11,            
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(/* COORDS VAR */)
      };

      var mapElement = document.getElementById('my_map');
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

      var image = '/wp-content/themes/example/img/foo.png';
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(/* COORDS VAR */);
      var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image
      });
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

I've tried multiple things but i'm wrestling too long. I basically was thinking i could pass the coords var to the init function like this:

- `function init(coords){}`
- `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){initialize(coords);});`

I also tried to set ajax `async: false`, and added `dataType: 'json'` but that didn't give me the opportunity to pass to the init function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that `init()` has already been run (thanks to the hook to `window.load` that is added) before your AJAX request returns. You need to remove that hook, and call `init` manually within the `success` handler. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
    var zipcode = jQuery('input#zipcode').val();    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
        data: {
            address: 'netherlands',
            components: 'postal_code:' + zipcode,
            sensor: false
        },
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            init(lat, lng);
        }    
    });   
});

function init(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,            
        center: latlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#my_map')[0], mapOptions);
    var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: '/wp-content/themes/decevents/img/marker_darkblue.png'
    });
}
```